# Is there any Builder class to construct KeyConditionExpression string for DynamoDB query expression?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-java-sdk

From the DDB [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression), `KeyConditionExpression` is a string to be passed when performing a query on a DDB table/ index.

This expression has a specific structure, so wanted to know if there is a Builder class to get this string?

From what I have searched, it looks like there is no such builder class and simple string concatenations like this are to be used.

```
String keyConditionExpression = "#" + "id" + " = " + ":" + "idValue"; // "#id = :idValues";
```

While this is simple, I feel this doesn't look clean.

Note: I am using DynamoDbMapper client (from `aws-java-sdk`)  to integrate with DDB.

Answer (score 1):

This ultimately depends on which client you are using. But there a numerous ways to build an expression without using a String. For example:

```
QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withHashKey("id", "my-id");

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);
```

I suggest reading over the API Reference Docs for the client you are using to find the most appropriate way for you.